# How to reference a variable within a variable YAML GitLab pipeline

Tags: variables, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I am using `env` as a (lowercase) input variable for my pipeline and
I want to be able to have this stage use the correct AWS account based on the environment I input. Right now I have it set just as AWS_ACCOUNT_DEV so I need to have separate stages.
I just want this one stage to be able to be used for all environments based on my input - how can I achieve this?

```
variables:
  AWS_ACCOUNT_DEV:     000000000
  AWS_ACCOUNT_NONPROD: 000000000

Import Alertmanager Endpoint:
  stage: import
  dependencies:
    - "Validate Credentials"
  tags:
    - ${runner}
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PROJECT_ID != $MONITORING_PROJECT_ID
  variables:
    AWS_IAM_DEPLOYER_ROLE: "arn:aws:iam::${AWS_ACCOUNT_DEV}:role/${runner_role}"
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out by adding:

```html
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PROJECT_ID != $MONITORING_PROJECT_ID
    - if: $ecs_env == "dev"
      variables:                              
        AWS_IAM_DEPLOYER_ROLE: "arn:aws:iam::${AWS_ACCOUNT_DEV}:role/${runner_role}"
    - if: $ecs_env == "nonprod"
      variables:
        AWS_IAM_DEPLOYER_ROLE: "arn:aws:iam::${AWS_ACCOUNT_NONPROD}:role/${runner_role}"
```